# Java: Problema com Substring

Tags: java, switch, case, substring

Criei um programa para traduzir notas musicais de um site para um formato mais legível, ele recebe e analisa cada dois dígitos de uma string procurando por eles (como chave) dentro de um hashmap, caso encontre, o int que ele retorna é usado em um switch que encontrará os caracteres correspondentes que serão gravados em uma nova string.

A novaString é uma variável de classe, ela é usada no método public traduzir para concatenar os caracteres traduzidos e é usada no método private traduzir quando o switch case 63 é chamado, nesse método private eu tento deletar o último caractere da novaString com substring, porém parece que estou editando uma cópia e não a variável em si porque nenhuma alteração feita nessa linha é salva.

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Resources r1 = new Resources();
        String texto = "[t8] ttt [r5] t r [r4] t y [u5] y\r\n" + 
                "[t8] ttt [r5] t t [w4] 5\r\n" + 
                "[t8] ttt [r5] t r [r4] t y [u5] y\r\n" + 
                "[t8] ttt [r5] t y [w4] [w5]\r\n" + 
                "[t8] t [y5] w [o4] i u [y5]\r\n" + 
                "u i [u8] y t [r5] t r [e4] [w5]\r\n" + 
                "[t8] t [y5] w [o4] i u [y5]\r\n" + 
                "u i [u8] y t [r5] t r [r4] t y [u5] y [t8]";

        r1.c1.gravar("Titanic", r1.traduzir(texto));

    }

}
```

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Resources {

    Map<String,Integer> example = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    public Conectar c1 = new Conectar();

    private String novaString = "";

    public Resources() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        bancoDados();

    }

    private void bancoDados() {
        example.put("1", 1); // dó
        example.put("1|", 2); // dó sustenido
        example.put("2", 3); // ré
        example.put("2|", 4); // ré sustenido
        example.put("3", 5); // mi
        example.put("4", 6); // fá
        example.put("4|", 7); // fá sustenido
        example.put("5", 8); // sol
        example.put("5|", 9); // sol sustenido
        example.put("6", 10); // lá
        example.put("6|", 11); // lá sustenido
        example.put("7", 12); // si

        example.put("8", 13); // dó
        example.put("8|", 14); // dó sustenido
        example.put("9", 15); // ré
        example.put("9|", 16); // ré sustenido
        example.put("0", 17); // mi
        example.put("q", 18); // fá
        example.put("Q", 19); // fá sustenido
        example.put("w", 20); // sol
        example.put("W", 21); // sol sustenido
        example.put("e", 22); // lá
        example.put("E", 23); // lá sustenido
        example.put("r", 24); // si

        example.put("t", 25); // dó
        example.put("T", 26); // dó sustenido
        example.put("y", 27); // ré
        example.put("Y", 28); // ré sustenido
        example.put("u", 29); // mi
        example.put("i", 30); // fá
        example.put("I", 31); // fá sustenido
        example.put("o", 32); // sol
        example.put("O", 33); // sol sustenido
        example.put("p", 34); // lá
        example.put("P", 35); // lá sustenido
        example.put("a", 36); // si

        example.put("s", 37); // dó
        example.put("S", 38); // dó sustenido
        example.put("d", 39); // ré
        example.put("D", 40); // ré sustenido
        example.put("f", 41); // mi
        example.put("g", 42); // fá
        example.put("G", 43); // fá sustenido
        example.put("h", 44); // sol
        example.put("H", 45); // sol sustenido
        example.put("j", 46); // lá
        example.put("J", 47); // lá sustenido
        example.put("k", 48); // si

        example.put("l", 49); // dó
        example.put("L", 50); // dó sustenido
        example.put("z", 51); // ré
        example.put("Z", 52); // ré sustenido
        example.put("x", 53); // mi
        example.put("c", 54); // fá
        example.put("C", 55); // fá sustenido
        example.put("v", 56); // sol
        example.put("V", 57); // sol sustenido
        example.put("b", 58); // lá
        example.put("B", 59); // lá sustenido
        example.put("n", 60); // si

        example.put("m", 61); // dó
        example.put("[", 62);
        example.put("]", 63);

    }

    public String traduzir(String tr) {



        for (int i = 0; i < tr.length(); i++) {

            String str;

            if(tr.length() >= i + 1) {
                str = tr.substring(0 + i, 1 + i);

                if (example.get(str) == null) {
                    if (tr.length() >= i + 2) {
                        str = tr.substring(0 + i, 1 + i);

                        if (example.get(str) == null) {

                        }                           
                        else
                            novaString += traduzir(example.get(str));
                    }
                }                   
                else {
                    novaString += traduzir(example.get(str));
                }
            }
        }
        return novaString;
    }

    private String traduzir(int i) {
        switch (i) {
            case 1 :
                return "1C "; // dó

            case 2 :
                return "1C# "; // dó sustenido

            case 3 :
                return "1D "; // ré

            case 4 :
                return "1D# "; // ré sustenido

            case 5 :
                return "1E "; // mi

            case 6 :
                return "1F "; // fá

            case 7 :
                return "1F# "; // fá sustenido

            case 8 :
                return "1G "; // sol

            case 9 :
                return "1G# "; // sol sustenido

            case 10 :
                return "1A "; // lá

            case 11 :
                return "1A# "; // lá sustenido

            case 12 :
                return "1B "; // si



            case 13 :
                return "2C "; // dó

            case 14 :
                return "2C# "; // dó sustenido

            case 15 :
                return "2D "; // ré

            case 16 :
                return "2D# "; // ré sustenido

            case 17 :
                return "2E "; // mi

            case 18 :
                return "2F "; // fá

            case 19 :
                return "2F# "; // fá sustenido

            case 20 :
                return "2G "; // sol

            case 21 :
                return "2G# "; // sol sustenido

            case 22 :
                return "2A "; // lá

            case 23 :
                return "2A# "; // lá sustenido

            case 24 :
                return "2B "; // si 


            case 25 :
                return "3C "; // dó

            case 26 :
                return "3C# "; // dó sustenido

            case 27 :
                return "3D "; // ré

            case 28 :
                return "3D# "; // ré sustenido

            case 29 :
                return "3E "; // mi

            case 30 :
                return "3F "; // fá

            case 31 :
                return "3F# "; // fá sustenido

            case 32 :
                return "3G "; // sol

            case 33 :
                return "3G# "; // sol sustenido

            case 34 :
                return "3A "; // lá

            case 35 :
                return "3A# "; // lá sustenido

            case 36 :
                return "3B "; // si 

            case 37 :
                return "4C "; // dó

            case 38 :
                return "4C# "; // dó sustenido

            case 39 :
                return "4D "; // ré

            case 40 :
                return "4D# "; // ré sustenido

            case 41 :
                return "4E "; // mi

            case 42 :
                return "4F "; // fá

            case 43 :
                return "4F# "; // fá sustenido

            case 44 :
                return "4G "; // sol

            case 45 :
                return "4G# "; // sol sustenido

            case 46 :
                return "4A "; // lá

            case 47 :
                return "4A# "; // lá sustenido

            case 48 :
                return "4B "; // si 


            case 49 :
                return "5C "; // dó

            case 50 :
                return "5C# "; // dó sustenido

            case 51 :
                return "5D "; // ré

            case 52 :
                return "5D# "; // ré sustenido

            case 53 :
                return "5E "; // mi

            case 54 :
                return "5F "; // fá

            case 55 :
                return "5F# "; // fá sustenido

            case 56 :
                return "5G "; // sol

            case 57 :
                return "5G# "; // sol sustenido

            case 58 :
                return "5A "; // lá

            case 59 :
                return "5A# "; // lá sustenido

            case 60 :
                return "5B "; // si


            case 61 :
                return "6C "; // dó

            case 62 :
                return "[";

            case 63 :
                novaString = novaString.substring(0, novaString.length() - 1);
                return "] ";

            default:
                return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Tudo que quero é quando o case 63 for chamado o caractere da última posição da novaString seja deletado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem que lembrar que `String` é uma coleção de caracteres análoga a ao `Array``:

- Como acontece com os `Arrays` o índice do primeiro caractere é o
  0(zero).
- O índice do último caractere, caso haja caracteres, é o comprimento
  do String menos 1(um). Isso pois o índice do primeiro caractere é 0, segundo é 1, do terceiro é 2,..., o índice do enésimoelemento(N) é igual a posição ordinal do enésimo elemento menos um, o que no seu exemplo pode ser traduzido com `novaString.length() - 1`

De posse da informação de que o índice do último elemento duma `String` é `length() - 1` para remover o último elemento duma Java `String` dentro do método `substring` é apenas retirar mais um elemento do comprimento da `String`:

```
novaString.length() - 2
```

Então seu `case 63` pode ser reescrito da seguinte forma:

```
    case 63 :
        // Verifica o comprimento da string para evitar o erro Index out of range(índice fora da faixa)
        novaString = (novaString.length() >= 2) ?  

                               // Caso comprimento seja maior ou igual a dois retorna o substring sem o último elemento.
                               novaString.substring(0, novaString.length() - 2) : 

                               //Caso o comprimento seja menor que dois retorna um string vazio.
                               "";
        return "] ";
```

Comment: Esse é um erro, se o case 63 fosse chamado esse erro ocorreria, mas não é o que está acontecendo.
Percebi que na lógica que usei o programa não está conseguindo formatar o texto adequadamente para os procurar os termos no hashmap, aparentemente apenas os case 62 e 63 não estão sendo chamados. Vou ter que rever a lógica do código para corrigir o problema.

Comment: Já que você vai rever a lógica do código considere usar o [JavaCC](https://javacc.org/) é um gerador de analisador. O analisador gerado lê uma gramática arbitrária, no seu caso pode ser notas musicais, e a converte em código Java.